# Определение длинны строки состоящей из char*

Tags: строки, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void NumberAsBinary(
    char *       _result, 
    unsigned int _number  
  )
{
  char tmp; 
  int i = 0;

  while (_number)
  {
    tmp = '0' + _number % 2;
    _result[i] = tmp;
    i++;
    _number /= 2;
  }
}

int main ()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
  {
    int randomNumber = rand() % 512;
    char * binNumber = new char [randomNumber];
    NumberAsBinary(binNumber, randomNumber);
    cout << strlen(binNumber) << endl;
    cout << binNumber << endl;
    delete [] binNumber;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Дело вот в чём, при выводе `cout << strlen(binNumber) << endl;`, даже если указать `char * binNumber = new char [5];`, то длина получается 22 а не 5.

Comment: @e13, исходя из заголовка вопроса, думаю, что  основная проблема в том, что Вы пока не до конца понимаете эту тему.

На самом деле  строка состоит **из char, а не из char \* !!!**.

Попробуйте еще раз перечитать учебник. И заодно прочтите о машинном представлении  целых (это как они из битиков в памяти строятся)

(в результате вопросы с `new` сами собой отпадут).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, не надо такую мешанину из C и C++ городить. Либо C, либо плюсы, гибриды никогда не получаются хоть сколько-нибудь пристойными.

Во-вторых, по коду. Это что такое?

```
char * binNumber = new char [randomNumber];
```

У меня нет ни одного подходящего слова чтобы объяснить смысл этого. Длина результирующей строки равна числу, так, что ли? Для записи строкового представления числа 134 в двоичном виде нужны 134 байта? Очевидно, это не так.

Дальше, `strlen()` может показать не только 22, а ещё и 33, 44, 125, 4387 и вообще что угодно. Потому что память какая-то выделяется (какая - другой вопрос), в неё что-то пишется, а завершающий `\0` - забыт.

Но прежде чем этот ноль писать, хорошо бы определиться с размером выделяемой памяти, потому что как сейчас - нельзя.

---

Если хочется решение на C++, то вот, набросал вариант на скорую руку:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

static string &
dec2bin(unsigned long a, string & B)
{
    B.clear();
    for( size_t i = 0; a && i < sizeof(a)*CHAR_BIT; i++ )
    {
        B += ( (a & 1) + '0' );
        a >>= 1;
    }
    // мы получили строку задом наперёд, переворачиваем
    reverse(B.begin(), B.end());

    if( !B.size() ) B = "0"; // проверку a == 0 можно и в начале сделать    
    return B;
}

int main()
{
    string B;
    cout << dec2bin(255, B) << endl;
}
```

Что тут можно:

1. Сделать функцию `dec2bin()` шаблоном, чтобы она принимала не только `unsigned long` (хотя это не так уж и нужно, так, для тренировки)
2. Если не нужно потом использовать строку именно как строку, можно накапливать единички и нолики в `std::vector<bool>`, вдруг пригодится
3. ???

Ну а если хочется разбираться с памятью, указателями и строками в C, то это совсем другой разговор, о другом.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо, я немного разобрался с выделением памяти, учить начинал с плюсов, скажите пожалуйста где я намешал сишки.

Comment: Определитесь, что конкретно хочется в данном примере:

- Разобраться с C++
- Придумать алгоритм на C
- Разобраться с памятью/строками в C

Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: @klopp, для полноты картины могли бы упомянуть, что таким образом мы получаем перевернутую строку бит (старшие биты **(в т.ч. незначащие нули(!!!)**) будут в конце).

--

@e13, если все же хотите в функции `char *` а не `string`, то буфер, в котором функция будет размещать `0` и `1`-ки можно было (для gcc/g++) описать так (и естественно, не нужно никакое динамическое выделение памяти):

     ...
     char binNumber[sizeof(typeof(randomNumber)) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
     // +1 это резерв под 0, завершающий строку символов

(а потом можно менять тип randomNumber, но не зависеть от C++ шаблонов)

Comment: @avp, всё думал что забыл - точно, перевернуть строку :) Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @klopp, да, теперь не будет. Ошибся.

--

Но по хорошему, string тут не нужен (лишнее это). Максимальный размер буфера известен еще при компиляции. Поэтому все же `char *` лучше.

Comment: Задание у меня было такое:

Описание.
Написать функцию, принимающую на вход произвольное целочисленное значение и возвращающую строку, содержащую его представление в двоичной системе исчисления.

Декларация.
void NumberAsBinary(
    char *       _result, // строка с результатом
    unsigned int _number  // произвольное число
  )

Ожидаемый результат.
Например, для числа 13 данная функция должна вернуть строку "1101".

Проверка работы.
Решение должно демонстрировать работу функции на примере 10 случайных чисел в диапазоне 0 до 512.

Comment: Просто при выводе был мусор, я добавил tmpResult[i]='\0' и поменял размер на char * binNumber = new char [11], для 512 в двоичной его хватает.
Конечно накрутил я там, но уже отправил, буду ждать ответа, что есть - то есть.

Comment: вот код:
     #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 void NumberAsBinary(
  char *       _result, 
  unsigned int _number  
   )
 {
   char tmp;
   int i = 0;
   char *tmpResult = new char[11];

   while (_number)
   {
  tmp = '0' + _number % 2;
  tmpResult[i] = tmp;
  i++;
  _number /= 2;
  tmpResult[i]='\0';
   }

   int k = strlen(tmpResult);
   
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(tmpResult); i++)
   {
  _result[i]=tmpResult[k-1];
  _result[strlen(tmpResult)]='\0';
  k--;
   }

   delete [] tmpResult;
 }

Comment: int main ()
 {
   for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
   {
  int randomNumber = rand() % 512;
  char * binNumber = new char [11];
  NumberAsBinary(binNumber, randomNumber);
  cout<<binNumber<<endl;
  delete [] binNumber;
   }

   return 0;
 }

Comment: @e13, если уж экономить, то под результат (числа до 512) достаточно 10 байт (с учетом завершающего нуля).

Совершенно очевидно, что `tmpResult` вообще не нужен. Попробуйте написать функцию, реверсирующую строку по месту

      char *str_reverse (char *str, size_t len); // Returns reverted str

и завершайте `NumberAsBinary()` так

      return str_reverse(_result, i - 1); // i это позиция завершающего 0

Тогда основной цикл в `main` можно записать так

      char binNumber[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << NumberAsBinary(rand() % 512, binNumber) << '\n';


IMHO красиво.

Comment: Места мало... (продолжение)


Также учтите случай, когда в `NumberAsBinary()` `_number` равен нулю (сейчас у Вас будет пустая строка).


Посмотрите внимательней на цикл `while`. Зачем на каждой итерации писать 0 в конец? Это можно сделать один раз после цикла (как раз, совместив с проверкой, что `_number` **был** нулем).

Естественно, вызывать `strlen()` в этой программе не нужно, поскольку в ходе формирования результата переменная `i` как раз и отражает длину строки.

--

Ну, и успехов в будущем программировании.